# В php foreach оставить только те значения, которые встречаются только один раз

Tags: php, циклы, php7, foreach, php5

Как в `php foreach` оставить только те значения, которые встречаются только один раз?
Для примера, если в foreach выводится такой результат:

`Array ( [0] => 21 )`, то истина.

Если:

`Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 21 [2] => 20 )`, то истина.

Если:

`Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 21 [2] => 20 [3] => 20)`, то ложь.

Если:

`Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 21 [2] => 20 [3] => 20 [4] => 25 )`, то истина.

Если:

`Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 21 [2] => 20 [3] => 20 [4] => 25 [5] => 25 )`, то ложь.

и т.д.

Comment: вопрос не так поставлен.... и можно упростить: если в массиве есть хотя бы одно число, которое встречается только один раз - истина, остальное ложь

Answer (score 0):

```
$countValues = array_count_values($array);    

$result = count(array_filter($countValues, function($item) {
    return $item === 1;
})) > 0;
```

В `$result` будет `true` если был найден хотя бы один элемент, который всетрчается единожды в массиве, в ином случа `false`